# Compare a short sentence with a longer in PHP

Tags: php, string, compare, cpu-word

So there is a comment detail.The person use a textbox to copy the full comment and the PHP code check the comment detail is in the comment. The user can not go to the next task until the comment and the comment detail have 80% match.

I try a lot of string compare function (e.g strcmp, similar_text) but nothing worked because the comment much longer than the comment detail and it not gives back correct percentage.

I also try to write a code which can handle this but it is get weird and give back more than 100% when i put a longer text( This is closer to the result but not perfect )

```
    $fcomment = $request->input('full_comment');
    $comment = $request->input('comment');

    $fc = explode(' ', $fcomment);
    $c = explode(' ', $comment);
    $match = 0;

    for ($i=0; $i < count($c); $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j < count($fc); $j++) {
            if ($c[$i] == $fc[$j]) {
                $match ++;
            }
        }
    }

    $length = count($c);
    $onepercent = $length/100;

    $percentage = $match/$onepercent;
    echo $percentage;
```

Here is an example of the comments:

Comment Detail:

Nunc vel tempor eros, sit amet suscipit justo.

Full Comment:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. **Nunc vel tempor eros, sit amet suscipit justo**. Proin lorem erat, tempus non neque ac, sollicitudin feugiat lectus. Phasellus justo lacus, aliquet nec dapibus ac, cursus sed quam. Aenean sagittis lacus justo, sit amet hendrerit mi pretium eget. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce cursus tincidunt mi sed tristique. Curabitur placerat at est eget congue.

Comment: stripos() maybe ?

Comment: yes i meant strpos smh

or a regex match

Comment: They are not giving back a percentage if I am rigth wich is the most important thing in this case.

Comment: similar_text can calculate a percent if you use the 3th parameter read http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Yes I know but it is not working well because it also counting the long text for the percentage and it gives back 39% when the comment detail is 100% in the full text. But i figured it out 2 minutes ago what was the problem with my code so it is working now. Thanks for the help!